# How to set channel positions/a channel mask in gstreamer?

Tags: python, audio, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I'm trying to get 28 channels out of a `jackaudiosrc` but as soon
as I connect, say, a `deinterleave` element, the source will fall back to
the 2-channel setup that works without any channel mask. My attempts at
setting a channel mask have been futile.

Here's what happens:

```
potential caps: audio/x-raw-float, endianness=(int)1234, width=(int)32, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)[ 1, 28 ]
filter caps: audio/x-raw-float, channels=(int)28, channel-positions=(GstAudioChannelPosition)< GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE >
actual caps: audio/x-raw-float, endianness=(int)1234, width=(int)32, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, channel-positions=(GstAudioChannelPosition)< GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_FRONT_LEFT, GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_FRONT_RIGHT >
```

And here's the Python code that produces that output:

```python
import pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst
import gobject
import gst.audio

gobject.threads_init()
pipeline = gst.Pipeline("mypipeline")
src = gst.element_factory_make("jackaudiosrc", "jacksrc")
pipeline.add(src)
srcpad = src.get_pad("src")
pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
print 'potential caps:',srcpad.get_caps()
sink = gst.element_factory_make("fakesink", "sink")
pipeline.add(sink)
filtercaps = gst.caps_from_string("audio/x-raw-float,channels=28")
filtercaps[0].set_value("channel-positions", tuple([gst.audio.AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE]*28))
print "filter caps:",filtercaps
src.link_filtered(sink, filtercaps)
pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
print 'actual caps:',srcpad.get_negotiated_caps()
#gst.DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE_WITH_TS(pipeline, gst.DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL, 'caps')
```

I also tried to set the caps of the output directly instead of using a
filter but that didn't do anything either.

Here's the output of that last bin-to-dot-file line (click to enlarge).

[image: dot file output for 0.10]

Here's a `gst-launch` line that works without an actual multichannel audio setup but does *not* actually reproduce the error, I believe because the `interleave` element sets the NONE caps correctly by default while the `jackaudiosrc` doesn't. Maybe it still helps people to play around with this issue who can't reproduce it themselves because of technical restrictions. Credit to http://tristanswork.blogspot.de/2008/08/multichannel-audio-with-gstreamer.html for the original launch line that I adapted.

```
gst-launch-0.10 interleave name=i ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! queue ! deinterleave name=o audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! queue ! i. audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! queue ! i. audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! queue ! i. o. ! queue ! fakesink dump=true o. ! queue ! fakesink dump=true o. ! queue ! fakesink dump=true
```

**Edit:** I now tried to do the same thing in GStreamer 1.x. The `tuple` data type is no longer accepted so here's what I came up with after having a look at others wrote channel positions directly to the `get_caps_from_string` function.

```
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstAudio
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline("mypipeline")
src = Gst.ElementFactory.make("jackaudiosrc", "jacksrc")
pipeline.add(src)
srcpad = src.get_static_pad("src")
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
print 'potential caps:', srcpad.query_caps()
sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("fakesink", "sink")
pipeline.add(sink)
filtercaps = Gst.caps_from_string("audio/x-raw, channels=(int)28, channel-positions=(int)< 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 >")
print "filter caps:", filtercaps
src.link_filtered(sink, filtercaps)
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
print 'actual caps:', srcpad.get_current_caps()
Gst.debug_bin_to_dot_file_with_ts(pipeline, Gst.DebugGraphDetails.ALL, 'caps')
```

The output both in text form and the graph are shockingly similar:

```
potential caps: audio/x-raw, format=(string)F32LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)[ 1, 28 ]
filter caps: audio/x-raw, channels=(int)28, channel-positions=(int)< 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 >
actual caps: audio/x-raw, format=(string)F32LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2
```

[image: dot file output for 1.4]